# fluent nhibernate outer join 2 query

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, fluent, linq-to-nhibernate

I am using [linq-to-nhibernate](/questions/tagged/linq-to-nhibernate) with fluent (c#), and I want to do the following:

I have two `IQueryable` interfaces, `relations` and `documentsrelations`.

The `relations` object contain a list of enterprises and the `documentsrelations` object contain a second list of enterprises.

I want to generate a new list of enterprises that contains the list of enterprises (`relations`) minus the second list of enterprises (`documentsrelations`).

In sql I would try with an outer join, but I don't know how to do with this.

**** DECLARATIONS ****

```
IQueryable<EnterpriseRelation> documentsrelations = 
    shared_doc.SharedIn.AsQueryable();

var relations = EnterpriseRelationService
    .QueryRelationsForEnterprise(LoggedUser.ActiveAsEnterprise)
    .Where(x => x.ContactingEnterprise.NIF == LoggedUser.ActiveAsEnterprise.NIF);
```

`relations` is also an `IQueryable<EnterpriseRelation>`.

I tried multiplied things, but it always tells me that it is not supported.

Some help?

Thanks!

Comment: You should show what you have tried. [Edit] your question.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing your entity primary key is `Id`, have you tried something like below?

```
var relations = EnterpriseRelationService
    .QueryRelationsForEnterprise(LoggedUser.ActiveAsEnterprise)
    .Where(x => x.ContactingEnterprise.NIF == LoggedUser.ActiveAsEnterprise.NIF)
    .Where(x => !documentsrelations.Select(dr => dr.Id).Contains(x.Id));
```

**Note:**

Using `.AsQueryable()` as you do in your question is most of the time a mistake. If `SharedIn` is not actually a queryable instance, it will just convert it to a linq-to-object queryable, executing in memory, not in database. And for your case, there are no need to have it as a queryable anyway, at least with my answer above, and unless it is already a queryable awaiting execution in db.

If my answer fails, try again without your `AsQueryable` call on `SharedIn`.